# Windows Phone 7 Bluetooth/Wi-Fi

Tags: silverlight, bluetooth, windows-phone-7, wifi

I would like to create application for Windows Phone 7, which will be communicating with desktop application via Bluetooth/Wi-Fi. Is there any API in Silverlight, which allows to use Bluetooth/Wi-Fi programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like bluetooth is going to be standard in the chassis spec. Unfortunately at this stage there is no api exposing Bluetooth functionality in the SDK. I think we'll have to wait and see on this one.

I understand devices will be able to inherently connect over wifi the same as 3g. No low level wifi specific api's known at this stage.

Comment: And what about Wi-Fi? Do you know about any Wi-Fi API in Silverlight?